# bindValue / bindParam vs array performance

Tags: php, pdo, bindvalue, bindparam

I have always passed an array of my values into execute as it seemed easier to read imo.  I was recently working on a script and noticed it was using bindParam and later came to find out how this passes the variable reference (I never knew).

With that said, in a current project I can think of quite a few uses for bindParam instead of my current array usage.

**With that said, is there any performance difference between bindValue/bindParam and using an array on execute... especially in the case of repeated loops?**  I find myself doing a lot of `$stmt->execute( array_merge($binding_clause, $binding) );` where I have a few binds that won't change and some that will, in loops of course, where as far as I can tell using bindParam would be perfect for this.

**Does adding the type (PDO::PARAM_STR, PDO::PARAM_INT) with the first have any performance over not doing so when using an array (I believe it is string by default with arrays)?**

Example difference between the two (these are prepared statements) :

```
$binding = array(
    'cw_account_id' => $_SESSION['user']['account_id'],
    'cw_date_start' => $date_start,
    'cw_date_end' => $date_end,
    'cw_start' => $b_counter * 500
);  

$stmt->execute($binding);

compared to

$stmt->bindValue(':cw_account_id', $_SESSION['user']['account_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':cw_date_start', $date_start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':cw_date_end', $date_end, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':cw_start', $b_counter * 500, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$stmt->execute();
```

**Aside from the questions above, would each `$stmt->bindValue()` here be another trip to the db as compared to one when using the array method?**

Aside from readability of code, and how bindParam references values, are there are performance positives/negatives between the two (small and large scale usage... repeated loops included)?

Comment: That's not even worth [profiling](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) (if you cared) in comparison to the database queries themselves, using a suitable schema/indexes, or asynchronous queries.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Aside from readability of code, and how bindParam references values, are there are performance positives/negatives between the two

No.

> would each $stmt->bindValue() here be another trip to the db

No.

Comment: Could you explain your answers?

Comment: `No.` (In reference to the first, very descriptive part of your answer) - this is incorrect. There are performance negatives/positives between the two (having an array, not having an array). They're just not noticeable on modern hardware. Now, if you tried to compare the two on a cheap Game&Watch-esque toy you got from McDonalds, you might notice a difference. In terms of practicality: it doesn't matter. You're not programming on a Atari 2600 and performing 12 queries; you're at least working on a 90's desktop, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: As far as *practice* goes, it is supposedly better to use the `bind` option as you're explicitly stating the relationship; in my opinion, it doesn't matter. I don't *want* to have to bind 8 times in a row, so the straight `execute` option is what I'd rather you. Use whichever you want.